# Доступ к Gii RBAC Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, безопасность

Поставил RBAC, в правилах прописал для ролей конкретные правила. Не пускает в Gii, и логично, ведь для него я правил не указывал, если я настраиваю доступ к какому то контроллеру вот так:

```
'debug/default' =>
                [
                    [
                        'actions' => [],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                ],
```

Как можно достучаться то Gii что бы открыть доступ?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:
в файле **config/web.php**
*Найди и замени*

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']],
    ];
}
```

Не забудь заменить **$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']** на свой IP